# Java file not showing in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create a new application in android studio, when I open a new project I don't see a Java file like this.
the difference between my project and other project
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG74s.jpg

Comment: Post your code here, not an link to an print screen of your code

Comment: what file is this? build.gradle? activity_main.xml? other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the app directory then you will have your java files appear?[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

[Java_file_path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crLZc.png)

If your looking for the file path to the java file that picture should help you.  Substitute "Myapp2"  for the name of your app.